# C++ Synchronized and Atomic Software Transactional Memory

Tags: c++, transactions, g++, stm, transactional-memory

I read the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/transactional_memory) guide over the sperimental feature of transactional memory and i try it.

I write some simple code with `sincronized` that as say cpp reference is not a transaction but only guarantees that the operation in the block are executed in a total order, the i write the same code with `atomic_noexcept` and `atomic_commit`, not with `atomic_cancel` that seems to be not yet implemented.

The doubt that i have is about the difference between `atomic_noexcept`, `atomic_commit` and `synchronized`, apparently they work in the same way, **except for the compilation error if a no **transaction safe** function is called in an atomic block**.

So I analyze the assembly code for the 3 variants, and result the same, as reported below:

**cpp atomic_noexcept:**

```
int a;

void thread_func() {
    
    atomic_noexcept
    {
      ++a;          
    }       
}
```

**assembly atomic_noexcept:**

```
thread_func():
        subq    $8, %rsp
        movl    $43, %edi
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        call    _ITM_beginTransaction
        testb   $2, %al
        jne     .L2
        movl    $a, %edi
        call    _ITM_RfWU4
        movl    $a, %edi
        leal    1(%rax), %esi
        call    _ITM_WaWU4
        call    _ITM_commitTransaction
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
.L2:
        addl    $1, a(%rip)
        addq    $8, %rsp
        jmp     _ITM_commitTransaction
a:
        .zero   4
```

**cpp atomic_commit:**

```
int a;

void thread_func() {
    
    atomic_commit
    {
      ++a;          
    }       
}
```

**assembly atomic_commit:**

```
thread_func():
        subq    $8, %rsp
        movl    $43, %edi
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        call    _ITM_beginTransaction
        testb   $2, %al
        jne     .L2
        movl    $a, %edi
        call    _ITM_RfWU4
        movl    $a, %edi
        leal    1(%rax), %esi
        call    _ITM_WaWU4
        call    _ITM_commitTransaction
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
.L2:
        addl    $1, a(%rip)
        addq    $8, %rsp
        jmp     _ITM_commitTransaction
a:
        .zero   4
```

**cpp synchronized:**

```
int a;

void thread_func() {
    
    synchronized
    {
      ++a;          
    }       
}
```

**assembly synchronized:**

```
thread_func():
        subq    $8, %rsp
        movl    $43, %edi
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        call    _ITM_beginTransaction
        testb   $2, %al
        jne     .L2
        movl    $a, %edi
        call    _ITM_RfWU4
        movl    $a, %edi
        leal    1(%rax), %esi
        call    _ITM_WaWU4
        call    _ITM_commitTransaction
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
.L2:
        addl    $1, a(%rip)
        addq    $8, %rsp
        jmp     _ITM_commitTransaction
a:
        .zero   4
```

How can they work differently? For example i report the explanation of different atomic block of cppreference:

> **atomic_noexcept**  : If an exception is thrown, std::abort is called
>
> **atomic_cancel** : If an exception is thrown, std::abort is called,
> unless the exception is one of the exceptions uses for transaction
> cancellation (see below) in which case the transaction is cancelled:
> the values of all memory locations in the program that were modified
> by side effects of the operations of the atomic block are restored to
> the values they had at the time the start of the atomic block was
> executed, and the exception continues stack unwinding as usual.
>
> **atomic_commit** : If an exception is thrown, the transaction is
> committed normally.

How can `atomic_noexcept` work differently from `atomic_commit` if has the same assembly code?
How can **syncronized block** work differently from **atomic block** if has the same assembly code?

EDIT:

All these test and assembly code are extracted from last version of GCC (V. 10.2)

EDIT2:

After some test and research i haven't found yet a logical explanation for the said different behaviour.

Comment: Perhaps the compiler noticed that exceptions can't be thrown so it compiled them the same way? Or perhaps you aren't looking at the exception handler?

Comment: what you mean with " you aren't looking at the exception handler", what i have to look? And where is the exception handler?